# Bitcoin Server won't connect, timeout error

Tags: bitcoind, server, connection

I am trying to run/sync bitcoind -server for the first time on linux and it is not connecting

end of Debug log gives me this...

```
new
Added 14 addresses from ::: 0 tried, 91 new
93 addresses found from DNS seeds
dnsseed thread exit
trying connection 69.64.34.118:8333 lastseen=117.2hrs
connection timeout
trying connection 10.0.0.2:8333 lastseen=354419.7hrs
connect() failed after select(): Connection refused
connection timeout
trying connection 62.245.238.146:8333 lastseen=96.2hrs
connection timeout
```

Does anyone have any suggestions. Is it perhaps a server firewall issue?

Answer (score 2):

Issue solved. Simple firewall issue, always unblock 8333